# Speed up 'if' conditions (verify / waiton)

Tags: tosca

**(Disclaimer: I'm quite new to Tosca but not to testing in general**)

**DESCRIPTION**

I'm automating a very dynamic page in Tosca, with content that is added (or not) as you progress through a form.

I do not have a testsheet at hand and do not have time to create one so I cannot use a template and the 'conditions' (I'm using TC-Parameters and they do not seem to apply to the 'Condition' column).

I wanted to use libraries as much as possible because most of the steps are the same, and there are a LOT of possible outcomes (I have more than 100 TCs to automate) so I'm trying to have my steps as 'generic' as possible, so that if the interface is changed in the future I'll be ale to maintain most of it 'centrally'.

**PROBLEM**

I've added four 'ifs' in strategic points. The problem is that an unsuccessful 'if' seems to hang for 10s, no matter what I use inside: 'verify' takes 10s & 'waiton' also takes 10s (although for the latter I modified the settings to 5s so I don't understand why).

I'm actually not interested in 'verify' waiting at all. I know that the content has either to be there or not at the precise moment where I have my condition. I'd be happy with a 1s delay, that'd be more than enough time for the app to display the content.

The TCs duration varies between 1m and 1m40s (4*10s if my 4 'if' are negative). It'd be great if I could speed it up, especially because most of the 'ifs' will NOT trigger. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try checking some settings regarding how long Tosca waits for Verify/Waiton:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Engine</kbd> > <kbd>Waiton</kbd> > <kbd>Maximum Wait Duration</kbd>

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>TBox</kbd> > <kbd>Synchronization</kbd> > <kbd>Synchronization Time out</kbd>

However, I've also found using buffered values to be more efficient time-wise for some of my testing scenarios.

Comment: hi - thanks! I did know the waiton settings (although I feel like they do not really change much...). I'll have a look into the Synchronization!

Comment: better late than never: the secodn set of settings did the trick! I'll mark this as the answer. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding TCPs and buffering them, in order to check them as conditions (not sure why Tosca requires the intermediate buffering step but that does the trick). Now I can configure whether my tests should expect a given follow-up item or not. It's a lot of extra configs but at least my tests are nicely modular.